# Windows 8 not showing in Grub

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, grub, kali-linux

Windows 8 not showing in Grub `fdisk -l`

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  1465149167   732574583+  ee  GPT
```

and here's what I see in gparted which the 290gb and 221gb partitions are my partitions I had in windows.

[image]

I have already tried `sudo update-grub` and `update-grub2` but it doesn't show up.

Comment: It's Kali Linux btw.

Comment: Is your PC booting both OS successfully?

Comment: no. I can't see win8 in grub to boot it.

Comment: What was your setup originally? Was Win8 pre-installed? Is your system based on UEFI?

Comment: Yes. came with win 8.. turned of the secure boot and switched to legacy.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/720691/issues-installing-kali-linux-alongside-windows-8 This answer _might_ help you. Although the error was different, The answer contains quite a few options. Try it.

Comment: not the same problem.. I can boot into win 8 if i switch back from legacy  but kali wont show up

Comment: Yes. That's coz Kali is installed using the legacy bootloader, and Win8 is installed on the UEFI version. Can you do one thing? Just disable secure boot, and try installing Kali while still in UEFI mode. >